# Undefined index on assigning, not on var_dump

Tags: php, arrays

The code below gives me an `Undefined index: data` when I assign `$arr['data']` to the variable but if I `var_dump($arr['data'])` it just shows me the contents of `$arr['data']` (because it DOES exists!)

Also if I `var_dump($arr);` it shows me an array with the key `data`.

What in the hell is causing this?

```
foreach($batchResponse as $key => $bR){

    $arr = json_decode($bR['body'], true);

    $results[$venue_ids[$key]['facebook_id']] = $arr['data'];

}
```

**$batchResponse:**

```
array(43) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["code"]=>
    int(200)
    ["headers"]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(27) "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ["value"]=>
        string(1) "*"
      }
      ...
    }
    ["body"]=>
    string(29255) "{"data":[{"description":
```

Comment: can you show var_dump(batchResponse) result?

Comment: Are you sure that `var_dump($arr)` is showing you an array and not an object?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. It outputs `array(2) { ["data"]=>` and when I `var_dump($arr['data']` it also displays the contents of 'data' without any errors

Comment: According to your input, the error is not related to $arr variable, check the value of the expression "$venue_ids[$key]['facebook_id']", namely the variables ($venue_ids) and ($key) and see what you get.

Comment: Even when I assign `$arr['data']` to a new variable (like $new) it keeps saying 'Undefined index: data'